# Stored procedure dynamic where with date

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I must have a query with a dynamic where but I have a problem with the dates.

The error message is

> Msg 295, Level 16, State 3, Line 45
> Failed to convert a string to data type smalldatetime

Here is my procedure

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[baro_search1]
    (@name varchar(20),
     @begin_date varchar(30))
AS
BEGIN    
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;

    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @NomFilter  VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @DataFilter VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @all        VARCHAR(2)   = '1'

    SET @NomFilter = CASE WHEN @name IS NULL OR @name = '' THEN '''' + @all + ''' = ''' + @all + ''''
    ELSE 'Nome like ''%' + @name + '%'''
    END

    SET @DataFilter = CASE WHEN @begin_date IS NULL OR @begin_date = '' THEN '''' + @all + ''' = ''' + @all + ''''
    ELSE 'DataConsenso = ''%' + @begin_date + '%'''
    END

    SET @SQL = 'SELECT \*
    FROM \[dbo\].\[AnagDati\] anag
    WHERE '  + @NomFilter + ''
    \+ ' AND ' + @DataFilter + ''

    PRINT (@SQL)

    EXEC(@SQL)
END

EXEC \[dbo\].\[baro_search1\] 'name','2015-11-22 00:00:00'
```

Comment: This line :- `'DataConsenso = ''%' + @begin_date + '%'''` remove the `%` sign. Should be `DataConsenso =  @begin_date`. Also change to use `sp_executesql` so that you can pass in parameter (@begin_date). And `@begin_date` should be declare as `date` or `datetime`, not as string data type

Comment: Whats with all the backslashes?

Comment: Why are you passing `@begin_date` as a `varchar` instead of a `date`?

Comment: Also -> `SET NOCOUNT OFF;` WHY?

Answer (score 3):

I would do it this way:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.baro_search1
  @name       varchar(20),
  @begin_date date
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  
  DECLARE @name_pattern varchar(22),
          @sql nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT * FROM dbo.AnagDati
            WHERE DataConsenso = @begin_date';

  IF LEN(COALESCE(RTRIM(@name), SPACE(0))) > 0
  BEGIN
    SET @name_pattern = CONCAT(char(37), @name, char(37));
    SET @sql += N' AND Nome LIKE @name_pattern;';
  END
  
  PRINT @sql;

  EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql, 
    N'@begin_date date, @name_pattern varchar(22)',
    @begin_date, @name_pattern;
END
```

Then to call it:

```
EXEC dbo.baro_search1 @name = NULL,    @begin_date = '20220329';
EXEC dbo.baro_search1 @name = ' ',     @begin_date = '20220329';
EXEC dbo.baro_search1 @name = 'Aaron', @begin_date = '20220329';
```

- Do as much as you can to avoid doubling and quadrupling single quotes in your queries. And you should always strive to parameterize any user input to avoid SQL injection, which means never just blindly concatenating executable strings with user input. See [Dynamic SQL](https://sqlblog.org/dynamic-sql).
- Since you have dynamic SQL anyway, only add the condition for name when you actually want to check for it, rather than always having the check but having some convoluted `CASE` expression that simply becomes `1=1`. This way you get a different plan when you need to search that column, compared to when you don't. See [Kitchen Sink](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example) and [Dynamic Search Conditions](https://sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html).
- Never pass dates using a string data type, and always use unambiguous, non-regional date formats. `yyyyMMdd` is infinitely better than `yyyy-MM-dd`, especially if any users may use a non-US English locale or language. See [Dating Responsibly](https://sqlblog.org/dates).

Answer (score -3):

change the data type for @begin_date to nvarchar and that should work.